# Replacing values in a list inside a Linq query with values from a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, asp.net-core

This inside a linq query.

I'm having lots of trouble with Linq today.

Consider this line inside a Linq query:

```
EnginePartNames = x.EngineParts.Select(t => t.PartId).ToList(),
```

The left side, `EnginePartNames`, is an ICollection of type string.

The right side, `x.EngineParts.Select(t => t.PartId).ToList()`, is a generic list of type long.

I have this dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> partName = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {5763, "5.7 Engine"},
            {3511, "8-speed Transmission"},
            {8552, "Crankshaft"},
            {9127, "Cylinder Heads" }
        };
```

How would I iterate through the right side list inside my linq query, and replace each PartId with the string from the partName dictionary?

I tried this:

```
EnginePartNames = partName[x.EngineParts.Select(t => t.PartId)].ToList()
```

But it's giving me this error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'int'

So I get that there's a problem with converting the value in the select statement, which is a long, to the int in the dictionary.

So I tried this:

```
EnginePartNames = partName[Convert.ToInt32(x.EngineParts.Select(t => t.PartId))].ToList()
```

and get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So at this point Im kinda lost...I don't know what to try next...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, it should be something like that

```cs
EnginePartNames = x.EngineParts.Select(t => partName[t.PartId]).ToList();
```

You get the part name from a dictionary by key, represented by `PartId`. It works, since [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.item?view=netframework-4.8) of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` accepts parameter of `TKey` type and returns a value of type `TValue`.

To join the `EnginePartNames` into one string with spaces or commas (according to comments) you should use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) method

```cs
EnginePartNames = x.EngineParts.Select(t => partName[t.PartId]);
var result = string.Join(" ", EnginePartNames);
```

Comment: Exactly - in C#, types are always your friend.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Comment: Hi Pavel, it's working, but I can't figure out how to modify the output.  Currently it's creating an array of partNames, which is great, but it's being written to the screen liked this:  5.7 Engine,8-speed Transmission,Crankshaft ... there is no space between the comma and the next word.  Do you know of a way to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell It's correct behavior, to insert a space a comma you should pass the result to `string.Join` method, like `string.Join(" ", EnginePartNames)`